# How useful is glGetUniform?

Tags: opengl, glsl

My question is this. What is the usefulness of this feature? I know I get the value of a uniform variable, but what good is it? example:

I assign the value of a
uniform variable from my C / C + + program.

```
    Program  -> glUniform*(...);  -> Shader -> glGetUniform*(...)
```

With glGetUniform I get the value of this or any other variable, but uniform ... Since I can get the value directly from my application and since I can not directly assign a value to a uniform variable within shader, what is the usefulness of this feature?

```
    Program  -> glUniform*(...);  -> Shader -> glGetUniform*(...)
       |
       V
  uniform value
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The primary use for `glGet*()` functions is for debugging.  You almost never want to use them in your actual <s>rending</s> rendering code because it requires that the GL driver finishes any pending operations before returning the value, to ensure it is accurate.  This means it will be *much* faster to just cache the state you care about client-side.

Comment: Very Well friend. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: `in your actual rending code` - My rendering code quite often turns out to be rending code. +1 for making me snort ;)